# Is there a way to override the default JS error messages?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm guessing the answer to my question is no, but since I don't know enough about how `Error.prototype` works I figured it was worth asking: is there any way to change the error messages from the errors in Javascript?

For instance, if I get an error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
```

is there any way to change things such that I instead get:

```
TypeError: You expected an array but it wasn't an array dummy!
```

I thought about using a global error handler and then rethrowing them, but that would only work for uncaught errors.  Is there any `Error.prototype` method I can change (or any other way) to do this?

Not at all important, just curious.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify two points:

1) I understand how `try`/`catch` works, but what I'm asking about is whether there is a way to control the messages generated *before* the error is thrown/caught (presumably by overwriting a method of `Error.prototype`).

2) An answer of "no there is no way to do this, all generating of JS error messages is handled internally and the JS code has no way to control it" would be perfectly legitimate (... if that's the case).

Comment: Have you tried using `try..catch..finally`?

Comment: I doubt it, besides replacing that error message with yours can lead to confusion, since not all iterables are arrays. You can always catch those errors where you are expecting an array though and throw your own TypeError with a more appropiate message.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, I understand how error handling works ;)  I was asking if there was a way to change what error messages get generated, ie. how to change what happens *before* the error is thrown.  @ MinusFour, as for it not being a good idea, I agree: I was really just curious if it was possible (and who knows, it might be warranted in a very limited set of cases).

Comment: Why do you need a custom error message? What is the code which actually renders the error?

Comment: This is a question about what is/isn't possible with JS errors, not a question about a specific error-handling case, so there is no specific code.  As for why, please see the last sentence of my question: I'm simply trying to understand whether there is a mechanism exposed that allows JS code to control error messages generated internally (ie. not errors I catch and rethrow or errors I generate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the `TypeError` class, not one of these methods.

```
const overridableMessages = [{
  search: 'TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable',
  replace: 'TypeError: You expected an array but it wasn\'t an array dummy!'
}]

class TypeError extends window.TypeError {
  constructor (message) {
    super(message)
    overridableMessages.forEach((overridableMessage) => {
      if (this.message === overridableMessage.search) {
        this.message = overridableMessage.replace
      }
    })
  }
}

window.TypeError = TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {alert('Error : '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);return true;}
// general error handler
```

Also:

```
try { 
}
catch(err) {
alert(err); // here put your case with your messages.
}
// routine error handler
```

HIH,

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my question.  As I mentioned a global error handler (ie. `window.onerror =`) would only address the uncaught errors, and as for caught errors ... I wasn't asking how to catch errors so much as I was asking how to change the error messages JS generates.

Comment: Your question was:  is there any way to change the error messages from the errors in Javascript? **alert('Error : '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber)** change the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but I found this line on the MDN which seems to pretty clearly answer things:

> The global Error object contains no methods of its own, however, it does inherit some methods through the prototype chain.

Since the only methods it gets through the prototype chain are `toString` and `toSource` (neither of which controls an error's generated message), it appears (unless I'm missing some other mechanism that isn't `Error.prototype`-related) that there is no way to accomplish what I asked.

Comment: The constructors themselves are responsible for setting up the errors message. Technically though changing the message can be as simple as just writing to the `message` prop of the error. You can try replacing the constructors with your own that can override the message but there's no guarantee that they'll end up using that they don't keep a reference to the original constructor internally. This might be different across implementations.